# Uploading Multipart Files with Uppy/Laravel/Vue

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, amazon-s3, uppy

I'm using [Uppy's Vue components](https://uppy.io/docs/vue/) to handle uploading large files and I'm having trouble getting it to work.

I've followed the suggestion by Janko [here](https://github.com/transloadit/uppy/issues/1189#issuecomment-445521442) which involves setting the *companionUrl* in Uppy to point to my server, then write the necessary routes/functions to process the requests.

Everything is working until I try to fire the AWS "completeMultipartUpload" call.

```php
$result = $client->completeMultipartUpload([
    'Bucket'          => 'bucket-name',
    'Key'             => $key,
    'UploadId'        => $uploadId,
    'MultipartUpload' => [
        'Parts' => $formattedParts,
    ],
]);
```

I get the following error:

```
"Error executing "CompleteMultipartUpload" on "https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/NewProject.png?uploadId=nlWLdbNgB9zgarpLBXnj17eOIGAmQM_xyBArymtwdM71fhbFvveggDmL6fz4blz.B95TLhMatDvodbMb5p2ZMKqdlLeLFoSW1qcu33aRQTlt6NbiP_dkDO90DFO.pWGH"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/NewProject.png?uploadId=nlWLdbNgB9zgarpLBXnj17eOIGAmQM_xyBArymtwdM71fhbFvveggDmL6fz4blz.B95TLhMatDvodbMb5p2ZMKqdlLeLFoSW1qcu33aRQTlt6NbiP_dkDO90DFO.pWGH` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
    <Error><Code>InvalidPart</Code><Message>One or more of the specified parts could not be found.  The part may not have be (truncated...)
    InvalidPart (client): One or more of the specified parts could not be found.  The part may not have been uploaded, or the specified entity tag may not match the part's entity tag. - <Error><Code>InvalidPart</Code><Message>One or more of the specified parts could not be found.  The part may not have been uploaded, or the specified entity tag may not match the part's en"
```

I think that the problem is I've tried translating the JS found [here](https://github.com/transloadit/uppy/blob/fffd8ce4d8bac984eec8de5481d5a9bc795dd843/packages/%40uppy/companion/src/server/controllers/s3.js#L165-L192) to PHP, but although it's returning a URL, it's not correct. The notable difference is that I'm not passing an "UploadId" or a "PartNumber".

I've scoured the AWS docs, Google, Stackoverflow, Ask Jeeves, etc and couldn't find a PHP equivalent of the ["getSignedUrl" method](https://github.com/transloadit/uppy/blob/fffd8ce4d8bac984eec8de5481d5a9bc795dd843/packages/%40uppy/companion/src/server/controllers/s3.js#L178-L191)

```php
public function signPartUpload(Request $request, $uploadId, $partNumber)
{
    $client = new S3Client([
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region'  => 'us-east-1',
    ]);

    $key = $request->has('key') ? $request->get('key') : null;

    if (!is_string($key)) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 's3: the object key must be passed as a query parameter. For example: "?key=abc.jpg"'], 400);
    }

    if (!intval($partNumber)) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 's3: the part number must be a number between 1 and 10000.'], 400);
    }

    //Creating a presigned URL
    $cmd = $client->getCommand('PutObject', [
        'Bucket' => 'bucket-name',
        'Key' => $key
    ]);

    $response = $client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');
    $presignedUrl = (string)$response->getUri();

    return response()->json(['url' => $presignedUrl]);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the PHP equivalent of the `getSignedUrl` method.

```php
$command = $this->client->getCommand('UploadPart', [
    'Bucket'        => $this->bucket,
    'Key'           => $key,
    'PartNumber'    => $partNumber,
    'UploadId'      => $uploadId,
    'Body'          => '',
]);
```

Here's my solution:

```php
/**
 * Create a pre-signed URL for parts to be uploaded to.
 * @param Request $request
 * @param string $uploadId
 * @param int $partNumber
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function signPartUpload(Request $request, string $uploadId, int $partNumber)
{
    $key = $request->has('key') ? $request->get('key') : null;

    // Check key
    if (! is_string($key)) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 's3: the object key must be passed as a query parameter. For example: "?key=abc.jpg"'], 400);
    }

    // Check part number
    if (! intval($partNumber)) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 's3: the part number must be a number between 1 and 10000.'], 400);
    }

    // Create the upload part command and get the pre-signed URL
    try {
        $command = $this->client->getCommand('UploadPart', [
            'Bucket'        => $this->bucket,
            'Key'           => $key,
            'PartNumber'    => $partNumber,
            'UploadId'      => $uploadId,
            'Body'          => '',
        ]);

        $presignedUrl = $this->client->createPresignedRequest($command, '+20 minutes');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return response()->json(['error' => $e->getMessage()], 400);
    }

    // Convert the pre-signed URL to a string
    $presignedUrlString = (string) $presignedUrl->getUri();

    return response()->json(['url' => $presignedUrlString]);
}
```